# What are the consequence of $\limsup_{x\to x_0}f(x)\leq \ell$ or $\limsup_{x\to x_0}f(x)\geq \eta$?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm always confuse with this limsup (especially of the form $\limsup_{x\to x_0}$.

What are the consequence of $\limsup_{x\to x_0}f(x)\leq \ell$ or $\limsup_{x\to x_0}f(x)\geq \eta$ ? Which information do we have ?

Answer (score 2):

$\lim \sup_{x \to x_0} f(x) \leq l$ is equivalent to: for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that $f(x) <l+\epsilon$ whenever $|x-x_0| <\delta$.

$\lim \sup_{x \to x_0} f(x) \geq l$ is equivalent to: for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists a sequence $x_n \to x$ with $ f(x_n) >l-\epsilon$ for all $n$.